# OS boot in a multiprocessor system

Tags: operating-system, multiprocessing

In a single processor system, when powered on the processor starts executing the boot rom code and the multiple stages of the boot. However how does this work in a multi process system? Does one processor act as the master? Who decides which processor is the master and the others helpers?
How and where is it configured?

Are the page tables shared between the processors? The processor caches are obviously different, at least the L1 caches is.

Comment: It is both OS and hardware specific. See [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/)

Comment: you can find many info about this type of stuff in an Symmetric multiprocessing booting on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Multiprocessor Booting**

1 One processor designated as ‘Boot Processor’ (BSP)

*– Designation done either by Hardware or BIOS*

*– All other processors are designated AP (Application Processors)*

2- BIOS boots the BSP

3- BSP learns system configuration

4- BSP triggers boot of other AP

*– Done by sending an Startup IPI (inter processor interrupt) signal to
the AP*

[look here](http://machineryequipmentonline.com/electric-equipment/microprocessor-boot-code-multiprocessor-boot-sequences/) 
and [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/readings/ia32/MPspec.pdf)  for more details